# Static property in ASP.Net based on session will be shared across all users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-members

For following 2 static properties, will both be shared across all users in an ASP.net web site? It seems Property2 will be shared among all users of the ASP.Net web site, but not sure about Property1.

```
public static object Property1 {
get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["some_key"]; }
set {  HttpContext.Current.Session["some_key"] = value;}
}

public static object Property2 { get;set;}
```

Comment: Property1 for sure would not. It's obviously tied to a session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Property1 is only in scope for the user's current session. The static part doesn't change that since it's just a wrapper around session that points to user specific data.

Property2 is a regular static property that is the same for all users.

Comment: Isn't Property2 based on implicity defined private class level variables like 'private object _property2;'. In that case it would be different for each user?

Comment: If any user assigns a value to property2 it will be seen by all other users since it's a static property defined at the type level. Property1 is a special case since it's wrapping session which is user centric data

Comment: OK. I think the implicitly defined private level variable for Property2 would also be defined as static by the CLR. But, if we defined explicitly a private non-static variable for Property2 then I guess Property2 would behave like a non-static property.

Comment: If the property is static you can't define instance level backing fields. It won't compile

Answer (score 1):

The getter/setter methods within Property1 will reference the particular session.  Since Property2 does not have any custom getter/setter, the underlying private variable is stored application-wide, i.e. will be shared among all users of the ASP.Net website.

From a learning standpoint, this is a good example to see the difference. The ability to turn a static into something 'un-static-y' shows the flexibility within coding, however in practice you would probably want to avoid calling the Property1 static, mainly because your static Property is not following the behavior of a static variable once you reference session variables.  It may work exactly as you want, but other developers coming in after or with you may be confused about why it needs to be static.  Every situation is different, however here a static property referencing a single session appears to create a clash of intent, if you will.